# refactoring object methods on javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods, refactoring

I have an object make = {};
I created object methods ( make.a(), make.h1() ) where each method creates a tag element

I created a JSFiddle of what I did:  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cruzj/hpep8rfj/)

I want to create many tag elements like that.

Is there any way to avoid repeating

```
    return document.createElement('tagName');
```

each time?

Comment: What I mean is: can I use tag element names as parameters in a "super-method" who create methods?, so in that "super-method" I just write once:   return document.createElement(this);    or something like that

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the tag name to the function.

```
  var make = {};

make.el = function(elem) {
    return document.createElement(elem);
};



var h1 = make.el('h1');
h1.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
document.body.appendChild(h1);

var a = make.el('a');
a.href = 'http://jsfiddle.net';
a.innerHTML = 'JSFiddle';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hpep8rfj/1/

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using eval command, although it's not recommended usage.

```
var make = {};

var tags = "a,h1,h2,h3,p,div,span";   // and so on

var arr = tags.split(",");
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    eval (" make[arr[i]] = function (){return document.createElement('"+arr[i]+"')};");
}


var h1 = make.h1();
h1.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
document.body.appendChild(h1);
```

see http://jsbin.com/xodiwenepa/1/edit

Comment: Thanks IT goldman! That's exactly what I was looking for. Why is it not recommended?